# calling a fuction and variables from another class in java

Tags: java, string, function, class, methods

I have created a script and divided it into two class "Main" and "Switchclass".
The "Switchclass" contains the "switch" method and the "Main" class contains the main method. I want to call the "switch" method in "main" and when the "switch" method is called the "switch" will call a variable "userin" (i.e. the scanned value in "main"). I am having difficulty in doing the both.

Here is my present code, what can i add to it;

"Main" class with "main" method;

```
package Prog;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String userin = null;
    for(;;)
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
                     userin = scan.nextLine();
        if(userin == "exit")
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        //I want to call the "switch" method here.

        }

    }
}
```

"switchclass" class with "Switchcase" method;

```
package Prog;

public class Switchclass {

public static void Switchcase() {
        //After calling this method, i want to assign "userin" variable to 
       "usersw"
        switch (usersw)
               {

               }
       }

}
```

Comment: Switchclass.switchCase()

Comment: So your Switchcase method needs to take an argument of type String named usersw, and the main method needs to call the method with userin as argument: `Switchclass.switchcase(userin)`. You'll also need to learn to respect the Java naming conventions, and to compare strings. Google for "how to compare strings in Java". https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: In addition to what @JBNizet said, these things are very much the basics of the language. You could start [right from the beginning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is when you need a *parameter*.

One of the cases where you need a parameter is when your method needs some information that it can't get for itself (in this case, `userin`), so the caller (`main`) has to give it the required information.

Add a parameter to the `switchcase` method. It seems like you want to call it `usersw`:

```
public static void switchcase(String usersw) {
```

And you can call the method like this in `main`:

```
Switchclass.switchcase(userin);
```

Also, note that you shouldn't compare strings with `==`, use the `equals` method instead.

```
if (userin.equals("exit"))
```

Comment: In "Switchcseclass" it shows error in usersw = Main.main(userin); and suggets to change the "main" method from void to string which is not possible. What can i do

Comment: @Shantanuvidwans You don't need the line `usersw = Main.main(userin);`. I never told you to add such a thing. Delete it and add the parameter `usersw` as I have shown.